# How to read from stdin in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, pipe, stdin

I can read from stdin in an R script:

```
$ echo "some text" | Rscript script.R
```

Note: using Docker and the [`rocker/r-base`](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/r-base/) image you can run:

```
$ echo "some text" | docker run --rm -i \
    -v $(pwd):/usr/src/app rocker/r-base \
    bash -c 'Rscript /usr/src/app/script.R'
```

**sript.R**:

```
f <- file("stdin")
i <- readLines(f)
close(f)
cat(i)
```

Now I want to reproduce this behaviour in shiny:

```
$ echo "some text" | shiny-server
```

Note: or with docker using [`rocker/shiny`](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/shiny/):

```
$ docker run --rm -it -p 80:3838 -v $(pwd):/srv/shiny-server/ rocker/shiny bash
# and then run in the container
$ echo "some text" | shiny-server
```

**app.R**:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("example"),
    sidebarPanel(),
    mainPanel(textOutput("my_stdin"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$my_stdin <- renderText({
        f <- file("stdin")
        i <- readLines(f)
        close(f)
        i
    })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Why is there no output from shiny?

The actual szenario is reading streaming data from `$ nc -u -l 1.2.3.4 1234` but the simple example above also illustrates my problem.